# Поймать все нажатия клавиш...

Tags: windows, winapi, c++

Здравствуйте.

Хочу написать программу, в которой предусмотрен hotkey... Как можно это организовать? Можно на WinApi? Да и вообще, можете обьяснить подробно процесс перехвата в Windows.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [About Hot Key Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775233(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Элемент управления WinHotkeyCtrl](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/controls/WinHotkeyCtrl.xml)

Простой пример.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int _cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR * argv[])
{
    if (RegisterHotKey(NULL, 1, MOD_ALT | MOD_NOREPEAT, 88)) {
        _tprintf(_T("Alt+X была нажата\n"));
    }

    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
        if (msg.message == WM_HOTKEY) {
            _tprintf(_T("WM_HOTKEY было получено\n"));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: MOD_NOREPEAT-это что за число??? Компилятор ругается...

Comment: Шлю 1-работает... Поясните что это.. А так всё работает, спасибо за пример!!!

Comment: MOD_NOREPEAT: Изменяет поведение горячих клавиш так, что длинные нажатия не вызывают несколько уведомлений.

Comment: Я возился-возился, так и не понял. где регистрируется клавиша x???

Answer (score 0):

Горячие клавиши вообще принято делать в акселлераторе клавиш - специальном типе ресурсов.

Заведи булевый массив для всех клавиш. При обработке сообщения WM_KEYDOWN заноси нажатую клавишу как нажатую, а при WM_KEYUP - обратно. По этому массиву можно будет определить, какие кнопки нажаты.

Comment: А если окно не активно это будет работать?

Comment: Вряд ли. Если надо, то для проверки нажатых клавиш лучше использовать GetAsyncKeyState. Только на неё антивирус ругается, пишет, что эта программа - клавиатурный перехватчик.